# Php pdftk remove page and the fill form

Tags: php, pdftk

I use pdftk to fill a form, no problem. I now want to both fill the form and remove certain pages. Is this possible in one command in pdftk? Tried below but returns an error.

passthru( '/usr/bin/pdftk template.pdf cat 1 fill_form fdfdatafile output - ');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to run one operation after the other in two separate commands.

Comment: Many thanks @notautogenerated ! Do you have any source for examples how to execute/chain commands with pdftk and php? Looked all over the place with no success.

Comment: Do you use https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk/ ? I think that supports chaining commands.